# How To Match Repeated String

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm very new to StackOverflow

I have a problem:

```
Dim sample As String = "<b>test string any value </b> <b>This Continue line here </b>"

Dim ra As New Regex("<b>(.*)</b>")

Dim m As Match = ra.Match(sample)
If m.Success Then
   MsgBox(m.Groups(1).Value)
End If
```

But I got this output:

```
test string any value </b> <b>This Continue line here
```

Comment: How is that a problem? What output did you expect?

Comment: What was your expected output?

Comment: The real problem here is [trying to parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/399649) Why would you do that when VB.NET has such good XML support?

Answer (score 4):

Make the `*` multiplier non-greedy by adding a question mark after it, to make the expression match as little as possible instead of as much as possible:

```
Dim ra As New Regex("<b>(.*?)</b>")
```

When the multiplier is greedy, `.*` will match everything to the end of the string, then it will backtrack until it finds `</b>`, which will be the end of the second tag. With a non-greedy multiplier it will start by matching zero characters, then increase the match until it finds `</b>`, which will be the end of the first tag.